# What Exactly is Step Size in Gradient Descent Method?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Gradient descent is numerical optimization method for finding local/global minimum of function. It is given by following formula: $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha \nabla f(x_n) $$ There is countless content on internet about this method use in machine learning. However, there is one thing I don't understand and which I couldn't find even though it is basic.

What exactly is step size $ \alpha $ ?

Wikipedia states that it is tunning parameter in optimization algorithm which I understand, but not enough is being said about it to be considered a definition. Dimension analysis states that its dimensions should be $\frac {(\Delta x )^2} {\Delta y}$  which I am not sure how to interpret.

Comment: There is no fixed step size.  If you pick a step size that is too small, it will take forever to get close to the answer.  If you pick one that is too large, you will overshoot the minimum and fail to converge.  One possibility is to try to find the sweet spot, but another is to start with a high step size and decrease it over time, so that you can quickly get near the optimum, and then be careful not to overshoot it.  This is similar to something like simulated annealing.

Comment: Yes, but what is it exactly? How to we define it?

Comment: It’s a number that you get to pick.

Comment: What I mean is why is $ \alpha \nabla f(x_n) $ equal to $ \Delta x$? Why does multiple of these two quantities define new value of $x$? I do understand general idea of gradient descent, but I don't quite understand how do we exactly compute new iterands in this method in sense that gradient of function defines change in $f$ not change in $x$ and so if we multiply by $ \nabla f(x_n) $ we should define $\Delta f$ not $ \Delta x $.

Comment: If you're asking this, then you do not understand the general ideal of gradient descent.  The gradient tells you the direction in which your function is increasing/decreasing the fastest, and so in order to maximize/minimize your function, you move in that direction, in a hill climbing fashion.  But while the gradient tells you which direction is steepest, it doesn't tell you how far in that direction you want to travel.  Therefore, you multiply the gradient by a parameter of your choosing in order to control how far you travel.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Gradient magnitude gives the value of maximum function increase at the point. However, it gives change in function value not how much do independent variables change and formula written above wants to compute new value of x (new iterand) not new value of f.  If we take single variable function (f(x)) for sake of simplicity, gradient becomes simply derivative $\frac {df} {dx}$ and derivative defines change in FUNCTION VALUE (f) at the point not change in x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134151/discussion-between-aaron-and-dario-miric).

Answer (score 1):

One way to picture it, is that $\alpha$ is the "step size" of the discretization for the differential equation
$$
\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -\nabla f(x(t))
$$
Lets first analyze this differential equation. Given an initial condition, $x(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the solution to the differential equation is some continuous time curve $x(t)$. What property does this curve have? Lets compute the following quantity, the total derivative of $f(x(t))$:
$$
\frac{df(x(t))}{dt} = \nabla f(x(t))\cdot \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -\nabla f(x(t))\cdot \nabla f(x(t)) = -\|\nabla f(x(t))\|^2 <0
$$
This means that whatever the trajectory $x(t)$ is, it makes $f(x)$ to be reduced as time progress! So if our goal was to reach a local minimum of $f(x)$, we could solve this differential equation, starting from some arbitrary $x(0)$, and asymptotically reach a local minimum $f(x^*)$ as $t\to\infty$.

In order to obtain the solution to such differential equation, we might try to use a numerical method / numerical approximation. For example, use the Euler approximation:
$$
\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \approx \frac{x(t+h)-x(t)}{h}
$$
for some small $h>0$. Now, lets define $t_n := nh$ with $n=0,1,2,\dots$ as well as $x_n := x(nh)$. Hence, we can write our approximate differential equation as:
$$
\frac{x_{n+1} -x_n}{h} = -\nabla f(x_n)
$$
or equivalently:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n -h\nabla f(x_n)
$$
So, this algorithm is the discrezation of the continuous time differential equation we had before. Ideally, if $h\to 0$ we would obtain the nice property that $f(x)$ always decreases along the trajectory $x(t)$. Hence, for sufficiently small $h$, and sufficiently regular $f$, the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ will comply the same property: $f(x_n)$ should decrease at each step.

How should I choose $h$ ($\alpha$ in your case)? It depends, for some particular $f(x)$ you may be able to compute the maximum value of $h$ until the condition $f(x_{n+1})<f(x_n), \forall n\geq 0$ no longer holds. However, in most cases, you know that this works for sufficiently small $h$ and you will need to find a suitable one by trial and error.

Regarding units, the step size has whatever units are needed to make sense of the algorithm. On this case they are not important. This an algorithm for which someone decided its dynamics and not a physical/natural phenomenon.

I hope this helps!